# Problem in rendering error page

Tags: error-pages

I have some problems for rendering a custom error page for my website. Joomla is installed at the root of my domain.

I have created an `error.php` page inside `templates/mytemplate/` directory but this page is not rendered every time I insert a wrong url.

Some examples follows to better explain my problem with typed url and corresponding obtained page:

- www.example.org/something-not-existing `-->` **not** custom error page (see below)
- www.example.org/index.php/something-not-existing `-->` home page
- www.example.org/index.php?option=com_component-not-existing `-->` custom error page, `404 Component not found`
- www.example.org/index.php?option=com_existing-component&view=not-existing-view `-->` custom error page, `500 View not found`

---

Not custom error page:

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /something-not-existing was not found on this
>   server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

---

Why I don't get the custom error page also in the first two cases?

Comment: Could you please add all the contents of your `error.php` file to http://pastebin.com so we can take a look?

Answer (score 1):

> ErrorDocument 404 /templates/mytemplate/error.php

Is NOT the way to do this. All Joomla requests get routed through index.php and NOT direct to the error page.

Add

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 401 default
```

in your .htaccess to overwrite your servers configuration and trigger Joomla's built in handler.  Also ensure that your server is configured to allow rewriting of urls. You should use the default Joomla htaccess.txt as a base for your own .htaccess file, with the inclusion of the above two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /templates/mytemplate/error.php
```

Comment: Thanks, this partially works. The server finds the correct error file to render but it seems that all joomla variables are undefined so I get inly a blank page

Answer (score 0):

This probably is because you don't use the `.htaccess` file (or it hasn't been correctly configured).

When typing your URL **without** `index.php`, it gives the standard 404 error page because Joomla is not even loaded, and can't present the custom 404 error page (I'm assuming this - not sure about the technical details).

Try renaming `htaccess.txt` to `.htaccess` in your Joomla root folder. You might have to uncomment the following line, but this depends on your server settings:

```
RewriteBase /
```

You should now get your custom error page for all your examples above.

Hope this helps.